# How to select multiple folder paths using FolderBrowserDialog control in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, user-interface

Is it posssible to select multiple folder paths from a browse dialogue box in VB.NET?

Please let me know if there is any link or reference.

Answer (score 7):

Citation from [here](http://www.ssware.com/articles/folderbrowserdialog-unmasked-everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-folder-browser-component-from-dotnet-framework.htm):

> **No Multiple Selection**
>
> The folder browser component does not
>   allow multiple folders to be selected.

So it's not possible. Fill a [TreeView](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/treeviewms.html) with directory informations, there is possible to select multiple nodes.