# How to select multiple folders

Tags: c#, winforms, directory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select multiple folder path usingt FolderBrowserDialog control in vb.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043468/how-to-select-multiple-folder-path-usingt-folderbrowserdialog-control-in-vb-net)

I want to select many folders for performing some operations on them, like selecting
many files with [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx).

The problem is that I can't select multiple folders in time with [FolderBrowseDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx).

What is the solution?

Comment: That's not really what it's for

Comment: FolderBrowserDialog sucks even in single selection , I can't imagine it doing multiple selection :P ... To be serious, unfortunately I guess you have to implement it yourself...

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewexplorer.aspx

And the closing of this as a duplicate is a little OTT - different languge and the linked question is not much of an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That component doesn't allow multiple selections, sorry.  You can, however, enable multiple selections in a [TreeView](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/treeviewms.aspx) to accomplish the task.

Answer (score 3):

Select it one by one. Or custom control: [File Explorer using Treeview controller](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/TreeViewFileExplorer.aspx) Here is what you need.

Don't forget to mark answer as correct if that helped you.

Answer (score 1):

`OpenFolderDialog`, apparently does not support multiple item selection:

[How to select multiple folder paths using FolderBrowserDialog control in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043468/how-to-select-multiple-folder-path-usingt-folderbrowserdialog-control-in-vb-net)