# How to select multiple folders with the FolderBrowserDialog in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have found multiple questions about this article, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11628021/c-sharp-how-to-customize-openfiledialog-to-select-multiple-folders-and-files), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5420189/how-to-select-multiple-folders), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1043468/how-to-select-multiple-folder-paths-using-folderbrowserdialog-control-in-vb-net),
and [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/756094/How-to-select-multiple-folders-using-Csharp), in which the basic answers are that the `FolderBrowserDialog` is not designed to select multiple folders.
Provided workarounds are to work with [TreeViews](http://www.arstdesign.com/articles/treeviewms.html), in which multiple files in multiple directories can be selected. This does not have my preference, since I do not want to select the individual files, but the folders they are located in.

However, the questions are all more that 10 years old, and don't really provide an answer. I was wondering whether it is possible by now to select multiple folders with the `FolderBrowserDialog`, or something similar.

The following code is able to select only one folder:

```
namespace FolderSelector
{
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    /// <summary>
    /// Select folders with browserdialog.
    /// </summary>
    public class FolderSelector
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Select folders with browserdialog.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Folders.</returns>
        public IList<string> SelectFolders()
        {
            // TODO: select multiple folders at once.
            var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog();
            if (fbd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                return new List<string>(new string[] { fbd.SelectedPath });
            }

            return new List<string>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The native `IFileDialog` interface has an option to multi-select see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifiledialog

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/33835934/14868997